# FB Like button on iphone browser - How to check if the user is already logged in on the FB native iphone app

Tags: authentication, iframe, mobile, facebook-like

I am implementing a FB like button iframe element on my mobile website. If a visitor to the site is logged into FB via the mobile browser, then the user has no problem pressing the like button. However, if the user is already logged into FB through their native FB app, my like button still redirects them to a browser login page.

Is there a way to check to see if the user is already logged in on their native app, and save them from logging in again through the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I think this is not possible, because this would require passing user session id from an application to another (FB native app to Safari)